# How to support multiple API hosts with Ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an Ember application (with ember data) that is run on a user's machine. There's an API server running on their machine, and one running online. I need to allow users to choose where a model is persisted (the API running on their machine, or the online API). So, two API hosts:

```
http://localhost:3000
and
http://api.example.com
```

When a user creates a record, they can set wether they want the record saved locally (through the local API server), or saved online. I persist this choice to a value on the record called dataSource.

So, depending on the record dataSource, I need to set the ember RestAdapter host for the model to the correct value. I understand one can override adapters on a per model basis. For example, I could create a RecordAdapter and manually set the host to a value. However, the host depends on a value in the record, and I'm not sure how to accomplish this with Ember Data, since the rest adapter "host" is a property, not a function.

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#property_host

User flow example:

- User creates new record, chooses the option to store this record locally.
- Record is persisted to localhost.
- User creates a new record, chooses the option to store this record online.
- Record is persisted to http://api.example.com
- Any time a record is saved, updated, deleted, etc, it must check the record dataSource to determine the api host to use in the operation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to override `buildURL` on your adapter:

As per Ember Data source, the default implementation for the RESTAdapter is:

```
/**
    Builds a URL for a given type and optional ID.

    By default, it pluralizes the type's name (for example, 'post'
    becomes 'posts' and 'person' becomes 'people'). To override the
    pluralization see [pathForType](#method_pathForType).

    If an ID is specified, it adds the ID to the path generated
    for the type, separated by a `/`.

    @method buildURL
    @param {String} type
    @param {String} id
    @param {DS.Model} record
    @return {String} url
  */
  buildURL: function(type, id, record) {
    var url = [],
        host = get(this, 'host'),
        prefix = this.urlPrefix();

    if (type) { url.push(this.pathForType(type)); }

    //We might get passed in an array of ids from findMany
    //in which case we don't want to modify the url, as the
    //ids will be passed in through a query param
    if (id && !Ember.isArray(id)) { url.push(encodeURIComponent(id)); }

    if (prefix) { url.unshift(prefix); }

    url = url.join('/');
    if (!host && url) { url = '/' + url; }

    return url;
  },
```

As you can see, `buildURL` on your adapter is provided the record so the URL can configured based on that.

The following example shows how you can choose the prefix based on the `isLocal` property on your model instances:

```
// app/adapters/application.js

import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';
var get = Ember.get;

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  buildURL: function(type, id, record) {
    var url = [],
        host = get(this, 'host'),
        prefix;

    // choose prefix based on model setting
    if (record && get(record, 'isLocal')) {
      prefix = 'http://localhost:3000';
    } else {
      prefix = this.urlPrefix();
    }

    if (type) { url.push(this.pathForType(type)); }

    //We might get passed in an array of ids from findMany
    //in which case we don't want to modify the url, as the
    //ids will be passed in through a query param
    if (id && !Ember.isArray(id)) { url.push(encodeURIComponent(id)); }

    if (prefix) { url.unshift(prefix); }

    url = url.join('/');
    if (!host && url) { url = '/' + url; }

    return url;
  },
});
```